# PHP mysql duplicated rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query in MySQL using php. The query is below

```
$sql = "select m.id, s_1.username player_1, s_2.username player_2, current_step, won
from {$table_prefix} match m left join {$table_prefix}session s_1 on s_1.id = player_1
left join {$table_prefix}session s_2 on s_2.id = player_2
where current_step < 10";
```

The problem I'm having the query works great but when it needs to be executed quickly(back to back) I'm getting duplicated rows. How would I go about preventing duplicate rows.

Thank you.

Comment: What kind of *duplicate*, same rows in one query result?

Comment: Are there duplicate rows in the database, or just in the response to your query? Do you get duplicates in one query, or from multiple queries that are supposed to return different results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use a DISTINCT to get only unique return rows.

```
$sql = "select DISTINCT m.id, s_1.username player_1, s_2.username player_2, current_step, won from {$table_prefix}match m left join {$table_prefix}session s_1 on s_1.id = player_1 left join {$table_prefix}session s_2 on s_2.id = player_2 where current_step < 10";
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/distinct-optimization.html